# Communicating a string of zeros and ones quantumly

Tags: quantum-computing, quantum-information

Alice wants to communicate an arbitrary $x \in \{0 ,1\}^n$ to Bob. Alice and Bob communicate
in rounds, in each round Alice (or Bob) applies a unitary transformation on his/her part and
transmits a qubit to the other side, until at the end Bob measures his state and tries to infer
x. The protocol is successful if for every $x \in \{0,1\}^n$ Bob succeeds with probability 1. Let
$n_A / n_B$ be the number of messages sent by Alice / Bob respectively.

Now I want to show that for any successful protocol we must have $n_A \geq  \lceil n/2 \rceil $, and $n_A+n_B \geq n$, and I need to show that the same argument above follows also for p-successful protocols, i.e if there's a p-successful protocol then the ineqaulities above should also follow for this protocol; a p-successful protocol is one in which Bob succeeds with probability p.

Any hints or prefereably bibliography where this or similar problem is disscused?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This paper proves the results you have described:

> Ashwin Nayak and Julia Salzman. [Limits on the Ability of Quantum
>   States to Convey Classical Messages.](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~anayak/papers/NayakS06.pdf) Journal of the ACM, 53(1):
>   184-206, 2006.